# Who publishes artefacts with groupId "com.force.api" to mvnrepository.com?

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api, partner-wsdl, com.force.api

Does anybody know who publishes force.com related jars under groupId [com.force.api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api) on mvnrepository.com?

Are these safe to use?

[image: artefact under com.force.api GroupId]

Bonus question - why there is no `force-tooling-api` artefact ? I understand that v38 WSDL of tooling api is broken, but does anyone know why there are no previous (good) versions available there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect they are originating from the WSC - [Force.com Web Service Connector](https://code.google.com/archive/p/sfdc-wsc/) (formerly https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc). I'm basing this off [com.force.api : force-partner-api : 38.0.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.force.api%7Cforce-partner-api%7C38.0.0%7Cjar) and Issue [com.force.api:force-partner-api: wrong default auth endpoint since 34.0.0](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/issues/110)

Additionally, files like [force-metadata-api-38.0.0.pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/force/api/force-metadata-api/38.0.0/force-metadata-api-38.0.0.pom) also reference back to https://github.com/forcedotcom/java-sdk.

The Salesforce WSC consumes the various SOAP APIs and generates the required Java integration code.

From sfdc-wsc-maven:

> Fork from [sfdc-wsc](http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/) [v22.0](http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/source/browse/?r=57) which project structure has been converted to a Maven one.
>
> Do not confuse with the other Maven port [force-wsc](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc) which is also a fork from [sfdc-wsc v22.0](http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/) and which source repository is located on [GitHub](http://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc).

So I think the mvnrepository you are references in a question is the "other Maven port" referenced above.

Comment: Hello Daniel. Thank you for your research. The issue you linked does indeed hints that one of WSC collaborators (gnguyen-sfdc) may be responsible for jar files uploaded on mvnrepository.com.